# Laravel Eloquent question, trying to group results via a table not directly related

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent

I feel like there is an easy way to do this but just not been able to find it... I am using Laravel to create a shop with product listings. I have 3 tables in my database:

*Categories Table* -
id,
name

*Products Table* -
id,
category_id,
brand_id,
name,
live (boolean)

*Brands Table* -
id,
name

On a category page, I want to list all the brands that have a live product attached. I feel like it should be something like a category has many brands through products but it just doesnt want to work.

Or should I be doing it a different way?

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: On Products table, shouldn't the columns be category_id and brand_id? Otherwise you would need to specify the keys to continue using the column names as you have it. How are you defining the relationships?

Comment: You're right Nick, they are actually called that. Will edit the question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your requirement, with hasManyThrough relation you wanted to list all brands of the category model through product model but your table structure is not correct. See laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

you can change your table structure or if that is not an option for you then you may try to get all brands with a live product from your current structure using whereHas like this:

Brand model:

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
}
```

brands with live products:

```
$brands_with_live_products = Brand::whereHas('products', 
function($q){
    $q->where('live', '==', 'true');
})->get();
// only brands that have live products will be selected
```

Comment: I get what I want by doing the following: 

`code` $brands = DB::table('brands')
->leftJoin('products', 'brands.id', '=', 'products.brand_id')
->leftJoin('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id')
->select('brands.id', 'brands.name')
->where('products.live', true)
->Where('categories.id', $category->id)
->groupBy('products.brand_id')
->orderBy('brands.name', 'Asc')
->get(); `/code`

Just thought there would be a more Laravel way of doing it?

Comment: This worked great! Just needed to change the internal query slightly to $q->where('live' , true) but its much cleaner than my workaround! Many thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]something simple like `$category->products->groupBy('brand.name')` will give you a collection grouped by the brand

Update:

```
$category->products()->where('live', true)->get()->groupBy('brand.name')
```

Or something like this

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Product::class);
    }

    public function liveProducts()
    {
        return $this->products()
            ->where('live', true);
    }
}

// Then you can call 
$category->liveProducts->groupBy('brand.name');
```

Comment: He wants to select all brands that have a live product which means live (boolean) is true

Comment: Maybe I misreading the OP but it also needs to take the category into account not just any brand with a live product